# How can i reference on_press to class test2?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to define a  `<Button>` outside of the  `<test2>` .
In this program how can i reference the `on_press:` in `<Button>` to `def e():` in `class test2(Widget):` to `print('hello')`
?

code:

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button

 
Builder.load_string("""



<Button>
    b:b
    id:b
    text:'text'
    on_press: 
 
 

    
<test2>
     
    GridLayout:
        size: root.width  ,root.height 
        Button:
     
        
    
 
                
""")

 

class test2(Widget):
    def e():
        print('hello')

class test(App):

    def build(self):
         
        return test2()


test().run()
```

Comment: Can't follow your issue. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: I want to create a class for `<Button>`  like the same way i created class  `test2` for `<test2>`.(to change some properties of `<Button>`  with functions)
How can i do that?

Comment: Why not using it like `<MyButton@Button>` ?

Comment: Then what exactly should i write inside `on_press: ` to call `def e():` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your issue properly, but from,

> how can i reference the on_press: in  to def e(): in class test2(Widget)...

It seems the following might be what you expect to happen.

```py
.
.
.
Builder.load_string("""


<MyButton@Button>
    # Dynamic class for button widget
#    b:b
#    id:b
#    text:'text'
#    on_press:


<test2>
     
    GridLayout:
        # You should initialize it atleast with cols or rows.
        cols: 1
        size: root.size
        MyButton:
            id: b
            text: "text"
            on_press: root.e()


""")



class test2(Widget):
    def e(self):
        print('hello')
.
.
.
```